# Which endpoint to I have to use to implement purchase product using credit in Nexudus?

Tags: express, integration

I am working on Express.js app that is integrated with Nexudus.
And I want to create an endpoint to enable the users to purchase products using their credits in Nexudus.
Which endpoint do I have to use for this?
As I checked, to purchase the products using card, I can use this endpoint: `/billing/coworkerinvoices/runcommand` after creating invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no endpoint to purchase products using credits in Nexudus.
By default when purchasing products, if user has some credits, then that will be used for purchasing, and invoice will be created for this amount: (`max(total product price - user's credit, 0)`).